# Alert on successful ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I built a chat system using ajax and jquery. i want an alert to pop up whenever a message is received.

Here's the ajax code to receive a new message

```
$(document).ready(function ajax(){
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'recieve.php',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(response){
      $("#message").html(response);
     },
     complete: function(){
      setTimeout(ajax,1000);
     }
  }); 
  });
```

where should i put alert("New message received"); so that it only pops up only when a message is received.

If i put alert in success function it is popping up every second.

Comment: Since your function is being executed every second the alert will popup every second. You need to check the response and conditionally alert based on whether there is a new message

Comment: i know that and just want to know how

Comment: try to use some framework that able to push message from server, without the need of clients to request every time. such as `signalr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var msg_res =''; //store the previous response
$(document).ready(function ajax(){
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'recieve.php',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(response){
      $("#message").html(response);
      //if response changed, not the same as in msg_res
      if(response != msg_res){
        msg_res = response; //store new response
        alert('New message received');
      }
     },
     complete: function(){
      setTimeout(ajax,1000);
     }
  }); 
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot :) this is exactly what i was looking for